# Using a browser as a WebRTC SFU

Tags: webrtc, openwebrtc

I'm building a webrtc project, and i need to:

1. route specific stream to specific users
2. record the streams on the server

I know this is typically the job of an SFU (selective forwarding unit)
However, before finding out about SFUs, I had previously started using browsers running on servers (i tested both chrome and firefox...using firefox for now), and it seems to be working.

I run my javascript and create peer connections and add the relevant streams just like i would on the clients.

I was even able to successfuly achieve multi-server hierarchy this way.

The only downside is see right now, is that the browsers decode the streams, which i believe would cause cpu overhead which i would not see using a proper SFU.

However, my project generally does 1 to many streaming (or rather *few* to many), and i need server side recording (which would cause an SFU to decode the streams anyway)

So, my question is..

**Why is using a browser as an SFU for webrtc a bad idea? I haven't seen a lot of people doing this, so there must be a reason**

Thank you